# Whirlfloc versus irish moss - pros and cons?

Tags: irish-moss, clarity, ingredients, techniques

What are the pros and cons of using irish moss versus whirlfloc tablets for clarifying beer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used Irish moss for many years before switching to whirlfloc. But I think that was an availability thing more than anything else.

**Irish Moss:**
*PRO*- Works great everytime.
*PRO*- Cheap
*PRO*- easily scaleable to any size batch
*CON*- Need to measure it out

**Whirlfloc:**
*PRO*- Works great everytime. I found it was even mildly better that IM, but that's tough to call.
*PRO*- Tablet is great and no measuring required, 5 gallon/s per tab.
*CON*- Tablet doesn't easily allow for a non-5gallon interval brew (say you did 8 gallon batches or a 3 gallon batch) This is trivial, but you could in theory over do it if you were doing small batches.
*CON*- More expensive than IM, but we're talking nickels not dollars.

**In my experience whirlfloc is easier to use, with few draw backs.  But in real world application the two are practically the same performance wise.**

Comment: I'd been told that Whirlfloc was 10 gallons per tab.

Comment: Interesting.  The whirlfoc I buy says 5 gallons per on the bag.

Comment: ... aaaaand I guess I was misinformed!

Comment: Boy, that extra nine cents a batch is really going to hit me in the pocketbook.  Srsly, I'm glad I don't need to split the things up anymore.

Comment: Google "whirlfloc half" and you'll find plenty of sources suggesting using half a tablet for 5 gallons.

Comment: Your first whirlfloc con isn't a con if you happen to own a knife of any kind. Our a blunt object of any kind, for that matter ;-P

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Whirlfloc works better.  I used Irish moss for my first couple of years, until I found Whirlfloc.  The first time I tried it I was **amazed** at how clear my wort got.  I chill by putting my kettle in a tub of cold water, and the visual effects of a Whirlfloc-treated wort when it hits about 25 degrees C are pretty cool.  I've never seen anything like it in my Irish Moss batches.

Yesterday I did my first batch going back to Irish Moss (I ran out of Whirlfloc) and it did **not** clear nearly as well as all my Whirlfloc batches.

Maybe I'm not using enough Irish Moss.  I'm using about 1 tsp in 5 gallons, re-hydrating it in warm water before putting it in for the last 10 minutes of the boil.  I think I'll try a couple more batches with IM, but if I don't get better results I'm going back to Whirfloc.

--

I should clarify that I'm talking about pre-fermentation clarity.  I get crystal-clear wort when using Whirlfloc, but I don't think I've ever seen that with Irish Moss.  But I'm not sure about the difference between the two post-fermentation.  I always have significant chill haze with both, and I haven't really compared the two.  But I've found that pre-fermentation the difference is striking.